# I have problems with bootstrap insert a template in codeigniter

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, codeigniter

Displays this error message.

> Font from origin 'http://127.0.0.1' has been blocked from loading by
>   Cross-Origin Resource Sharing policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin'
>   header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'http://localhost'
>   is therefore not allowed access.

Comment: Tried to google [some](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20035101/no-access-control-allow-origin-header-is-present-on-the-requested-resource)?

Answer (score 1):

Add this code in htaccess file..

```
# Allow access from all domains for webfonts.
# Alternatively you could only whitelist your
# subdomains like "subdomain.example.com".
<IfModule mod_headers.c>
  <FilesMatch "\.(ttf|ttc|otf|eot|woff|font.css|css)$">
    Header set Access-Control-Allow-Origin "*"
  </FilesMatch>
</IfModule>
```